# UIContextMenuConfiguration in objc

Tags: objective-c, ios13, xcode11

I would like to implement the UIContextMenuConfiguration in objC

There are many examples in swift , but I have to close a matter in objc ...

So in swift I found examples like this

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, contextMenuConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
    let configuration = UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil) { actions -> UIMenu<UIAction>? in
        let action = UIAction(__title: "Custom action", image: nil, options: []) { action in
            // Put button handler here
        }
        return UIMenu<UIAction>.create(title: "Menu", children: [action])
    }
    return configuration
}
```

In objc I can not define the actions

I can only produce mistakes ...

this is my example code...

```
   - (UIContextMenuConfiguration *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
contextMenuConfigurationForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
                                    point:(CGPoint)point API_AVAILABLE(ios(13.0)){


    BlogPost *blogPost = [self.blogPosts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UIAction * lettura = [UIAction actionWithTitle:@"Leggi"
                                             image:nil
                                        identifier:nil
                                           handler:^(UIAction *action){[self presentSF:indexPath];}
                          ];
UIMenu * menu = [UIMenu menuWithTitle:@"" children:@[lettura]];

    UIContextMenuConfiguration * config = [UIContextMenuConfiguration configurationWithIdentifier:nil
                                                                                  previewProvider:^ UIViewController* {
                                                                                      SFSafariViewController *previewSFController = [[SFSafariViewController alloc]                     initWithURL:blogPost.url entersReaderIfAvailable:NO];
                                                                                                previewSFController.preferredControlTintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
                                                                                                previewSFController.delegate = self;
                                                                                        return previewSFController;
                                                                                  }
                                                                                   actionProvider:nil];
    return config;
}
```

Someone can help me

Thank you so much in advance for your help

Vanni

Comment: And what's the question? What's the problem with your code?

Answer (score 4):

Sorry you people

I solved ...

I just had to pass an array...

```
actionProvider:^(NSArray* suggestedAction){return menu;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UIContextMenuConfiguration*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView contextMenuConfigurationForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath point:(CGPoint)point
```

{

```
UIContextMenuConfiguration* config = [UIContextMenuConfiguration configurationWithIdentifier:nil
                                                                             previewProvider:nil
                                                                              actionProvider:^UIMenu* _Nullable(NSArray<UIMenuElement*>* _Nonnull suggestedActions) {

    NSMutableArray* actions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //Your Action
    [actions addObject:[UIAction actionWithTitle:@"Favoritar!" image:[UIImage systemImageNamed:@"star"] identifier:nil handler:^(__kindof UIAction* _Nonnull action) {
        [self updateFavoriteTournament:self.tournamentArray[indexPath.row][@"_id"]];
    }]];
    
    
    UIMenu* menu = [UIMenu menuWithTitle:@"" children:actions];
    return menu;

}];

return config;
```

}